# Is "fortune favors the bold; cheek brings success" a popular idiom or proverb in English?

Tags: idioms, proverbs

I want to express the idea that:

1. If you want to be rich, you have to have guts and take a big risk.
2. If you want to achieve a high position in your society, like becoming a doctor or lawyer, you need to have a strong will (strong will is enough, not necessarily taking risk).

Does "fortune favors the bold; cheek brings success" express those two ideas?

Is it a popular idiom in English?

If not, what is another way to express those two ideas?

Comment: Note: You don't mean "big gut", this is a big gut! ---->  http://mozo.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Man-Fat-Gut-Belly-612x300.jpg  ---> You may want to say "have guts"

Comment: *Fortune favors the bold* certainly is. In fact, it was apparently an idiom in [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_favours_the_bold).  The earliest reference I can find for *cheek brings success* in Google books is a 1969 [English-Ukrainian phrase book](https://books.google.com/books?id=3VlgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cheek+brings+success%22&dq=%22cheek+brings+success%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBWoVChMI1OLxlI-KxwIVAqgeCh3uMQT5), and it appears thereafter only in foreign books of English idioms. Native English speakers have never heard of it.

Comment: In #2, you call it strong will, but it seems more like _perseverence_. I suggest you look for adages about perseverence. As for # 1, there are many related: No pain, no gain. For more relevant ones, look for adages about "dare", "chance", "risk" "brave", "venture".

Comment: I've heard/read the first part a number of times.  Not familiar with the second (though I've heard vaguely similar phrases).

Comment: And it should be noted that the two are saying essentially the same thing.  Neither expresses "no pain -- no gain".

Comment: The following quote is attributed to [J. Paul Getty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Paul_Getty) and it cleverly, I think, captures the idea without totally contradicting Matthew 5:5: "The meek shall inherit the earth, but not the mineral rights."

Answer (score 2):

The former is common. I have never heard the latter and it sounds as if it had been coined by an unskilled amateur epigrammist.

However, even if the latter of your two were a common idiom, you would be weakening the effect of the former by conflating them. Among the defining characteristics of a good idiom are concision and pithiness.

> [Fortune favors the bold.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fortune+favors+the+bold)

Says it all, especially for your original two-fold case, since *[fortune](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=fortune&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on)* has connotations of *material wealth* as well as *good luck* and *general success*.

---

**References:**

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs (As an alternative to "Fortune favors the brave")

Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, 1913

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a popular idiom in English?

No.  For my mostly American English ear, they are rare or unknown.

> If not, what is another way to express those two ideas?

1. Nothing ventured, nothing gained.  (Could be money and/or time.)
2. This isn't an adage, but there is an idiom that fits with your
   second idea, to pull yourself up by your bootstraps, for example:
        *My father pulled himself up by his bootstraps to become one of the richest men in the country.*  (from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+up+by+bootstraps)
        Also, the expression *make something of yourself* might be useful.  For example,
                *The nuns who taught him urged him to make something of his life and he did.*
   http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/make%20something%20of%20yourself/your%20life